# Convert JS code to PHP

Tags: php

```
var base64 = new Encodeutil.Base64Binary("");
    lstApplicableSubs = new Array(lstCategories.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < lstApplicableSubs.length; i++) lstApplicableSubs[i] = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < lstSubCategories.length; i++)
    {
        var map = base64.decode(lstSubCategories[i].validFor);
        for (var j = 0; j < lstCategories.length; j++)
        {
            var bits = map.charCodeAt(j >> 3);
            if ((bits & (0x80 >> (j & 0x07))) != 0) lstApplicableSubs[j].push(lstSubCategories[i]);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help convert this to PHP?

Below is var_export for object :

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'label' => 'Category',
       'name' => 'Category',
       'optionslist' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'label' => 'Category1',
           'value' => 'Category1',
        )),
        1 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'label' => 'Category2',
           'value' => 'Category2',
        )),
        2 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'label' => 'Category3',
           'value' => 'Category3',
        )),
        3 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'label' => 'Category4',
           'value' => 'Category4',
        )),
    )),
    1 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'label' => 'Sub Category',
       'name' => 'Sub_Category',
       'optionslist' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'label' => 'SubtCategory1',
           'validFor' => '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '',
           'value' => 'SubtCategory1',
        )),
        1 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'label' => 'SubtCategory2',
           'validFor' => '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '',
           'value' => 'SubtCategory2',
        )),
    ),
))
```

Comment: Which part of it did you get stuck at? What line ist troubling you?

Comment: I would say learn PHP. There is no converter here all are programmer.

Comment: @Martin : i am stuck with `var bits = map.charCodeAt(j >> 3); if ((bits & (0x80 >> (j & 0x07))) != 0)` i have not experice of working with that kind of code.

Comment: @Shakti : Well boss i am a new programmer. I thought this community was to help. Well if u feel like feel free to point me to some good tutorial on working with byte shift in php. Thanks.

Comment: Then your question is misleading. I suppose if you understood the functionality of these code lines (which I don't, because I didn't look at it in detail), you would know how to write them in PHP, too. So you might want to rephrase your question to "Can someone please explain the code in lines ... to me?" or such.

Comment: @Creative: Yes off course this community is still for help. But with some unspecified term & condition. You should know basics of language. You have enough to understand what is being explained here. You can not say write code for me directly on indirectly. And here you are asking to write code for you indirectly. You did not even tried to write the one line of code in php

Answer (score 1):

Without anything to test, or even know the purpose, here's my best-guess:

```
// assuming $lstCategories & $lstSubCategories exist already...

$subs = count($lstSubCategories);
$lstApplicableSubs = array_fill(0,$subs,array());
for ($i = 0; $i < $subs; $i++)
{
  $map = base64_decode($lstSubCategories[$i]['validFor']);
  $cats = count($lstCategories);
  for ($j = 0; $j < $cats; $j++)
  {
    $bits = ord($map{$j >> 3});
    if (($bits & (0x08 >> ($j & 0x07))) != 0)
      $lstApplicableSubs[$j][] = $lstSubCategories[$i];
  }
}
```

Also, this assumes `lstSubCategories` is a keyed array. If it's an object, change `$lstSubCategories[$i]['validFor']` to something like `$lstSubCategories[$i]->validFor`

Some documentation for you to learn from:

- [Working with Bits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)
- [`base64_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) (the same as creating a converter then called `.decode` from it)
- Since `charCodeAt` actually returns a unicode ordinal, you may want to look in to a [unicode conversion](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/) instead of the `ord` I used.
- The `{}` on the `$map` is a reference to the character index within that string. e.g. `$foo = 'Hi'; echo $foo{0} // returns H`

Comment: i get notice on following line : `$bits = ord($map{$j >> 3});`

`Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampplite\htdocs\phptoolkit\case.php on line 64`

Comment: @Creative: Then `$map` isn't being populated. Again, I don't have anything to test on, just what I see in the original code block. Make sure `$lstSubCategories` is an array, and see how you need to access `validFor`.

Comment: @Creative: So, assuming that `$lstSubCategories` is assigned the array from `[optionslist] => Array`, you should use the `$lstSubCategories[$i]->validFor` alternative.

Comment: But my problem is after substituting alternative for array for code takes a long time to execute and outputs that "Notice" and doesnt do anything...

Comment: @creative: Can you use `var_export` on your array so I can have it to test against? I'm lazy and don't want to re-create the structure. ;p

Comment: @Brad : problem is base64_decode outputs 0 length string for all means, outputs nothing. I cant find why. But that string is binary encoded base 64

Comment: @Creative: Echo the value going in to base64_decode--is there anything? Is it even finding the correct value to decode?

Comment: String that we are tyring to decode is base64 encoded binary string

Comment: When i echo the string that i am passing to decode function it prints junk characters. When i echo output of decode function its nothing

Comment: I think we will need to use "unpack" function but i dont know how to tell unpack its a base64 encoded data.

Comment: @Creative: I'm really at a loss here as I don't know enough about the system. Unpack can turn hex arrays in to data, and vise-verse, but you would know better than I if it's necessary. You may just need to make sure it's unicode since the charCodeAt tells me there's something going on there with unicode.

Comment: This is what i am trying to do in php [link](http://forums.sforce.com/t5/General-Development/Dependent-Picklists-in-Flex/m-p/51725)

Comment: @Brad : Thanks for all support looks like finnaly i achieved what i wanted. i still get notices how do i hdie them?

Comment: @Creative: What are the notices? Care to paste one?